# How to define a variable length type in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I try to declare a variable length type which contains a numeric array,

the type looks like

```
typedef struct MyType {
    double      count;
    double[]      lower;
    double[]      upper;
} MyType;
```

I find some words in postgresql website as follows:

"To do this, the internal representation must follow the standard layout for variable-length data: the first four bytes must be a char[4] field which is never accessed directly (customarily named vl_len_). You must use SET_VARSIZE() to store the size of the datum in this field and VARSIZE() to retrieve it. The C functions operating on the data type must always be careful to unpack any toasted values they are handed, by using PG_DETOAST_DATUM."

These words confuse me. For example, how to convert the values to toasted values?

Could you give me some examples or some suggestions about how to implement it?

Thanks very much

Comment: "Toasted values" refers to [TOAST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html), which is Postgres's mechanism for compressing and/or breaking up large values so that the main data fits in a fixed-sized page of storage.

Comment: Note that you never need to convert a value *to* TOAST, only provide the required structure so that Postgres can do so internally. What you will need to do is convert it *from* TOAST, but actually you don't need to know *how* that happens, just add the necessary macro call at the top of relevant functions to tell Postgres you need the full data.

Comment: Look at the source code of an existing type that is similar to yours.